# How to integrate biometric device of SecuSearch SDK PRO in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, biometrics

I am facing problem with integrating Bio metric device of Secugen Hemister Pro Duo SC PIV . I describing steps that I have done with this.

1. Install the driver of device
2. Install finger print recorder application
3. run Finger Print Recorder application, it is working fine at this level.
4. add SDK references in my asp.net website application
5. run the asp.net application it is listing in my device collection and working fine at this level also.
   Now
6. when I publish website and running in IIS enviroment this is not detecting device nor throwing any error.
7. I have enabled 32bit Applications true in IIS.
8. also published a test project as run unmanaged code condition 
   but not succeed.

Client and server are same machine. It is working in visual studio not in IIS on same machine . If I run the asp.net project from IIS , then "device open failed " error is thrown . But If I run the project in visual studio , then it is run successfully .

I have enabled windows authentication . Please tell me how can I solve this error .

Answer (score 0):

Check for some reason:

> 1. Is device driver installed on server (IIS) PC?
> 2. Is all dll included?
> 3. How about Project framework version ==> IIS.
> 4. Windows version internally.

Comment: 1. client and server is same . So device driver is installed in server pc . 
2. All dll is included . I do not know about other 2 options .